# Eslint & Prettier contradictory errors

Tags: node.js, eslint, prettier

Since I updated my dev dependencies (minor versions) I have contradictory errors from prettier.
I didn't modify my config files so I'm surprised to have these errors.

These are the concerned lines :
config.js

```
const {
  SERVER_PORT,
  NATS_CREDENTIALS,
  DB_CREDENTIALS,
  DATA_TYPES,
  EXCHANGES,
  USERS_API_URL,
  CONTROL_API_KEYS,
} = process.env;
```

When looking inside the file there is no visible error but if I run `yarn lint` I get this :

> Replace `⏎··SERVER_PORT,⏎··NATS_CREDENTIALS,⏎··DB_CREDENTIALS,⏎··DATA_TYPES,⏎··EXCHANGES,⏎··USERS_API_URL,⏎··CONTROL_API_KEYS,⏎}·=` with `·SERVER_PORT,·NATS_CREDENTIALS,·DB_CREDENTIALS,·DATA_TYPES,·EXCHANGES,·USERS_API_URL,·CONTROL_API_KEYS·}·=⏎·`  prettier/prettier

This shouldn't happen because if I fix the error the line length is 127, which is higher than the length set in the config (120).

After running `yarn lint --fix` then `yarn lint` again no error is found but when looking inside the file, eslint says the opposite :

> Replace `·SERVER_PORT,·NATS_CREDENTIALS,·DB_CREDENTIALS,·DATA_TYPES,·EXCHANGES,·USERS_API_URL,·CONTROL_API_KEYS·}·=⏎·` with `⏎··SERVER_PORT,⏎··NATS_CREDENTIALS,⏎··DB_CREDENTIALS,⏎··DATA_TYPES,⏎··EXCHANGES,⏎··USERS_API_URL,⏎··CONTROL_API_KEYS,⏎}·=` eslint (prettier/prettier)

Here are my configs :

`node v14.9.0`

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./src"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  }
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    commonjs: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ['airbnb-base', 'prettier'],
  plugins: ['prettier'],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
    log: true,
    cache: true,
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
  },
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': ['error'],
  },
};
```

.prettierrc

```
{
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "printWidth": 120,
  "useTabs": false,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "semi": true
}
```

Don't know if this will be useful but these were the versions I had before the update:
package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2"
  }
```

Does anyone know why I have this problem?
Thanks in advance!